# $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. If $Var(Y)= Var(X)/2 = 1/3$, what is $Var(2X-Y+1)$?

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. If $Var(Y)= Var(X)/2 = 1/3$. Find $Var(2X-Y+1)$.

Since it's independent then,
$Var(X)=Var(Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independence for two r.v.s $X$ and $Y$ is not $$\text{var}(X)=\text{var}(Y)$$; it is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$which has the following important consequence$$
E\{XY\}=E\{X\}E\{Y\}
$$Now, try to expand the terms and substitute for $E\{X\}$, $E\{X^2\}$, $E\{Y\}$ and $E\{Y^2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

> Since it's independent $Var(X)=Var(Y)$.

That is not true. The equality holds only if the variances are equal.

**Hints:**

The constant $+1$ does not affect the variance. Thus $Var(2X-Y+1)=Var(2X-Y)$.

Then $Var(aU-bV)=a^2Var(U)+b^2Var(V)$, if $U$ and $V$ are independent.

Can you proceed?

Comment: Is it 3? So I found that Var(X)=2/3.

Comment: Perfect. And yes, $Var(X)=2/3$

Answer (score 0):

By independence, we have: 
$$
\text{Var}(2x - Y + 1) = \text{Var}(2x) + \text{Var}(-Y) + \text{Var}(1). 
$$
The variance of a constant is $0$. Further, for any constant $a$ and random variable $W$, $\text{Var}(aW) = a^2 \text{Var}(W)$: 
$$
4 \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) + 0. 
$$
If $\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{2} = \frac{1}{3}$, then $4 \text{Var}(X) = \frac{8}{3}$. We have $\text{Var}(Y) = \frac{1}{3}$. 
$$\frac{8}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{9}{3} = 3.$$